# Store the same django model object in two database tables

Tags: django, django-models

I have two model objects like this. A RecordObject which gets updated daily and a RecordHistory table which stores all the updates/ changes to a RecordObject.

```
class RecordObject(models.Model):
      status = models.CharField()
      collection_date - models.CharField()

class RecordHistory(models.Model):
      status = models.CharField()
      collection_date - models.CharField()
```

I want to store the RecordObject in the RecordHistory table with all the updates. How can I store the RecordObject in the RecordHistory table without creating new RecordHistory  objects?

Comment: Why don't you want to use separate tables? What if later you add some extra fields to the `RecordHistory` (ex. modification date), then this would result an a large amount of `NULL`s for `RecordObject`, etc.

Comment: I have two separate tables, one for history and one for the live record data. I am not able to figure out how I can store the RecordObject directly in the RecordHistory Table (something on the lines of select * from tableA into tableB). Both the RecordHistory and RecordObject have the same column structure.

Comment: Have you looked at `pre_save` in django signals? ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/ )

Comment: I am looking for a way to cast the RecordObject into RecordHistory objects. Currently am creating a new RecordHistory object and assigning the fields from the existing RecordObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overridethe save method like this

```
class RecordObject(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField()
    collection_date - models.CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        RecordHistory.objects.create(status=self.status, collection_date=self.collection_date)
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I tried this approach as well, I am looking for a better way to avoid creating the extra RecordHistory objects.